# Integrate over Piecewise function efficiently

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

I have this Piecewise function:

```
Piecewise[{(t - #[[1]])^2, #[[1]] <= t && t < #[[2]]} & /@ 
  Partition[Sort[Join[{0}, RandomReal[{0, 10}, 20], {10}]], 2, 1], 0]
```

[image]

I would like to Plot the integral of this function. But when I do it like this:

```
Plot[{Evaluate@Integrate[pieces, {t, 0, x}]}, {x, 0,
   10}, Filling -> Bottom, PlotRange -> All]
```

it takes **114 seconds** to evaluate on a very capable computer.

Comment: It seems to help if you give `Integrate` the assumption `Assumptions -> {0 < x < 10}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `Piecewise` functions are a special case in `Integrate` if the integral is in the form of an **indefinite** integral. (One can add a constant as needed to adjust for a different starting point, but in the OP's example, it is unnecessary.) This evaluates relatively quickly:

```
foo = Piecewise[{(t - #[[1]])^2, #[[1]] <= t && t < #[[2]]} & /@ 
    Partition[Sort[Join[{0}, RandomReal[{0, 10}, 20], {10}]], 2, 1], 
   0];

AbsoluteTiming[
 ifoo = Integrate[foo, t];
 Plot[ifoo, {t, 0, 10}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The problem with the OP's code is that

```
 Evaluate@Integrate[pieces, {t, 0, x}]
```

is wrapped in a `List` and does not evaluate.  But fixing that still leaves the major problem, which is that

```
Integrate[foo, {t, 0, x}]
```

does not evaluate until `x` is numeric.  In fact, trying to evaluate the above gives a hint similar to what [Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods) suggested in a comment:

> Integrate::pwrl: Unable to prove that integration limits {0,x} are real. Adding assumptions may help. >>

Answer (score 3):

First thing I would note is that you should Integrate the function analytically before plotting it. To do so you should add your assumptions like already commented by other users (note that it is important to use set (`=`) instead of set delayed(`:=`) to do the integration only once):

```
f[t_] = Piecewise[{(t - #[[1]])^2, #[[1]] <= t && t < #[[2]]} & /@ 
          Partition[Sort[Join[{0}, RandomReal[{0, 10}, 20], {10}]], 2, 1], 0]

(*integrate analytically with additional assumptions*)
F[x_] = Assuming[x \[Element] Reals && 0 < x <= 10, 
          Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, x}]]
```

Then you can plot the function in a matter of a fraction of a second:

```
Plot[F[x], {x, 0, 10}, Filling -> Bottom, 
     PlotRange -> All] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Note that of course the main culprit in terms of computation time is to integrate `f` analytically, but this only hast to be done once. My general suggestion is to always do the pre computation first and the plotting afterwards. Here is the timing for the integration:

```
F[x_] = Assuming[x \[Element] Reals && 0 < x <= 10, 
    Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, x}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> > {10.3487, Null}

Comment: @MichaelE2: Added the information.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the same as Simon Woods's comment:

```
SeedRandom[1]

data = Partition[Sort[Join[{0}, RandomReal[{0, 10}, 20], {10}]], 2, 1];
```

You don't need the `And` with the inequality

```
f[t_] = Piecewise[{(t - #[[1]])^2, #[[1]] <= t < #[[2]]} & /@ data];
```

You need to add an assumption to the `Integrate` for it to evaluate

```
Plot[Evaluate@Assuming[x >= 0, Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, x}]], {x, 0, 10}, 
  Filling -> Bottom, PlotRange -> All] // Timing
```

[image]